# Joining two datasets in spark sql (java)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have 2 `Dataset`s with 4 columns each.

My dataSets:

```
'left':
a | b | c | d 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4

'right':
a | b | c | e 
1 | 2 | 3 | 5
```

What i would like to achieve:

```
a | b | c | d | e 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

My code:

```
left.join(right,left.col(a).equalTo(right.col(a))
                        .and(left.col(b).equalTo(right.col(b)))
                        .and(left.col(c).equalTo(right.col(c)))
                        )),"left");
```

I would like to add column 'e' from `right` to `left`, but what i get in return is:

```
a | b | c | d | a | b | c | e |
```

I get only a concatenation of the headers.
I thought from a logical point of view my query is correct, i am apparently failing at asking Spark how to perform the join.
Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the join with the following. You just need to specify the list of keys when they corresspond

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, 2, 3, 4)
).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")
val df2 = Seq(
  (1, 2, 3, 4)
).toDF("a", "b", "c", "e")

val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("a", "b", "c"), "left")
```